# How to properly deploy a smart contract and not lose money?

Tags: ethereum, smartcontracts, remix, ether

Yes, I have already read the information about how to pay ETH gas([website](https://www.blocknative.com/blog/eip-1559-fees)) and know approximately how to do it, but the amount of money to deploy is very large, so I want to ask if I will do it right:

I am going to deploy smart contract at **10 am - 4 pm** on Sunday. If you check last Sunday (https://ethereumprice.org/gas/), you can see a stable level around **71 - 69** gwei. I want to set Max Fee - **102 gwei** and Max Priority Fee - **2**. I make it so that even if the gas grows to 100 gwei, the transaction will be completed? Is that a good idea? And if gas costs **70 gwei** and the smart contract is successfully deployed, then I will be refunded *(102 - 72)* **30** gwei?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 3):

The gas is only refunded if the transaction is rejected. You will always pay the set gas price.

The best way to save money is not to deploy on Ethereum, but use an EVM compatible chain like [Polygon](https://polygon.technology/).

Comment: Thanks for answer! Check this link please: [link](https://www.blocknative.com/blog/eip-1559-fees#:~:text=This%20is%2057.6%20GWEI%20per%20gas%20less%20than%20the%20Max%20Fee%20you%20specified.%20That%2057.6%20GWEI%20per%20gas%20is%20effectively%20%27saved%27%20and%20will%20remain%20in%20your%20wallet.%C2%A0)
It says here that if you set 202 gwei and the current gwei is 142.4, you can keep 57.6 gwei in your wallet.

Comment: And how difficult to make smart contract if i have already written it on Solidity?

Comment: @maxet24 you should have no problems deploying the same contract in polygon, if you want try first in mumbai (polygon testnet) but deploys in polygon are a lot cheaper than in ethereum, there are other evm compatible chain that you can try, like arbitrum, moonbream, zksync, etc

Comment: @jhonny what do you think about SOL?

Comment: @maxet24 I haven't used it yet, but is not an evm based block chain, and the smart contracts should be written in rust, so al least that you have the time to learn about that or rewrite the smart contract I would recommend you to go to another chain